# Which items are lost when I'm brought back to life?

Tags: dont-starve

I activated a totem which means that when a few hounds came and killed me, I was brought back to life. I was resurrected at the totem and made the journey back to where I died to pick up my spilled items.

After picking everything up, I realized I was missing some of my items. It seems as though my gold and a large number of rock (but not all of it?) was taken. Which items do I lose when I die and come back to life? Are there certain items that will be lost every time I die? Or is it random and different items disappear each time?

Answer (score 7):

Usually, when you die, the items just drop to the ground. They are not supposed to dissapear.

Offcourse the normal things that can happen to stuff lying on the ground, still happen:

- Spoilables (most foods, meats, lightbulbs) can turn to rot,
- ashes can get blown away,
- meats can be eaten by dogs, spiders,
- food can be eaten by pigs
- flammable items can get struck by lightning and burnt
- gold, stone, flint, nitre, ... can get eaten by rock lobsters
- ...

If you die close to an edge, maybe some stuff could drop off - it happens when you kill mobs, but I haven't seen it happen to myself yet.

So unless you've got rock lobsters around, I'm a bit puzzled to where your gold and stone went.

Comment: Hmmm I've definitely died a few more times and lost items again including gold and stone. Something is amiss...

Comment: Reign of Giants adds moleworms that eat minerals, so rock lobsters are not the only threat. Even thermal stones (previously heat stones) are unsafe!